# Qt Image Merging

Tags: qt

I have 2 images in 2 labels (label_pic, label_pic_2) and I would like to merge these images (AND, OR ,XOR) but I don't know how, I am really new to the Qt platform, and I don't want to use OpneCV. Can somebody help me?

```
Here is my code:

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent *e){
    QMainWindow::changeEvent(e);
    switch (e->type()){
    case QEvent::LanguageChange:
        ui->retranslateUi(this);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //Opening picture file1:

    QFileDialog dialog(this);
    dialog.setNameFilter(tr("Images (*.png *.xmp *.jpg)"));
    dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open Image"), "C:/...", tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp"));

    //Select other pictures from the folder:

    if(!fileName.isEmpty()){
        QImage image (fileName);
        ui->label_pic->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    }

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    //Opening picture file2:

    QFileDialog dialog(this);
    dialog.setNameFilter(tr("Images (*.png *.xmp *.jpg)"));
    dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
    QString fileName2 = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open Image"), "C:/...", tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp"));

    //Select other pictures from the folder:

    if(!fileName2.isEmpty()){
        QImage image2(fileName2);
        ui->label_pic_2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image2));
    }

}



void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{

    QImage image1 = ui->label_pic->pixmap()->toImage();
    QImage image2 = ui->label_pic_2->pixmap()->toImage();

    QPainter painter1(&image1);
    image1.scaled(300,300);
    image2.scaled(300,300);

   // QImage image3 = pixmapMerge(iamge1,image2);



    //ui->label_pic_3->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage());
    /*
    QPainter painter;

    painter.drawImage(0, 0, image1);
    painter.drawImage(300, 0, image2);
    painter.end();
    */

}`enter code here`


P.S: The rest of my includes could not be shown, I don't know why, you can add them to your answers as well. Thank you in advice for any answers!
```

Comment: And what I didn't write is that, I would like to merge these pictures in the label_pic_3, pushing the button of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply to loop through the pixels and apply your operation:

```
QImage pixmapMerge(const QImage & a, const QImage & b)
{
    if (a.size() != b.size() ||
        a.format() != b.format())
        return QImage();

    QImage result(a.size(), a.format());
    for (int r = 0; r < a.height(); r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < a.width(); c++)
        {
            QRgb pixA = a.pixel(c, r);
            QRgb pixB = b.pixel(c, r);
            QRgb pixR = pixA & pixB;  // operation AND

            result.setPixel(c, r, pixR);
        } 
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note: 
This solution only applies to images of format `QImage::Format_RGB32` and `QImage::Format_ARGB32`. To convert from other formats, use the `QImage::convertToFormat()` function, or apply your operation differently. 
I can add an example solution also for the *8-bit (indexed)* images if needed.

For simplicity it's also reduced to the case of source images of same size.